# Stack views and arranged views property

Tags: ios

I can't figure out one thing about arranged views of stack views.

Let's say I have a stack view with three buttons in it. Do I have to add these buttons as `subviews` of the `UIViewController` before adding them to the arranged subviews of the stack view?

Comment: No, not required to add subviews separately. Add only stackview as subview from code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in the [`UIStackView` reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview#1653129). I've add emphasis to the revelant parts of the following excerpt:

> ### Maintaining Consistency Between the Arranged Views and Subviews
>
> **The stack view ensures that its `arrangedSubviews` property is always a subset of its `subviews` property.** Specifically, the stack view enforces the following rules:
>
> - **When the stack view adds a view to its `arrangedSubviews` array, it also adds that view as a subview, if it isn’t already.**
> - When a subview is removed from the stack view, the stack view also removes it from the `arrangedSubviews` array.
> - Removing a view from the `arrangedSubviews` array does not remove it as a subview. The stack view no longer manages the view’s size and position, but the view is still part of the view hierarchy, and is rendered on screen if it is visible.
>
> Although the `arrangedSubviews` array always contains a subset of the `subviews` array, the order of these arrays remain independent.
>
> - The order of the `arrangedSubviews` array defines the order in which views appear in the stack. For horizontal stacks, the views are laid out in reading order, with the lower index views appearing before the higher index views. In English, for example, the views are laid out in order from left to right. For vertical stacks, the views are laid out from top to bottom, with the lower index views above the higher index views.
> - The order of the `subviews` array defines the Z-order of the subviews. If the views overlap, subviews with a lower index appear behind subviews with a higher index.